# Right join or which type of join?

Tags: sql, join

I have 4 tables.

1 with just sitenames.

3 tables, which contains sitenames and the ammount of hits on them for different user types.

I need to make a report on the number of hits on thoose sites for each user type like this

Site Userype1hits Userype2hits Userype3hits

so in the select part I neeed to crosscheck with a table called noanswer

like

```
select *
from table
where site in (select site from noanswer)
```

So from what I understand I need to use join, and in this case right join?

How do I do with join in this query?

Comment: why `Userype`, and not `UserType`?

Comment: A LEFT JOIN B = B RIGHT JOIN A.

Comment: Cause of I spelled it wrong, multitasking like a mad man to get this done in time.

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Juan you are right, it's poorly asked. This time I can't even explain how stressed I am, I could have created some fake stuff to show you as I can't show you the real data. But I will try your lef join once the rest is ready soon.

Comment: well Gordon answer is a good start. But if you want specific help you need to post some sample data so we have something to work with. Otherwise we will be guessing.

Comment: select s.Site,s2.Total_hits as 'Internalusers',s3.Total_Hits as 'ExternalUsers', s4.Total_hits as 'Comapany2users'  from Database.Table as S
left outer join HITAnalyze.dbo.Internal as s2 on s2.site = s.Site
left outer join HITAnalyze.dbo.External1 as s3 on s3.site = s.Site
left outer join HITAnalyze.dbo.Company2 as s4 on s4.site = s.Site

This is how I did in the end. well, the external and so on is just fakenames for the post here of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use `left join`:

```
select sn.*, t1.cnt, t2.cnt, t3.cnt
from sitenames sn left join
     table1 t1
     on t1.name = sn.name left join
     table2 t2
     on t2.name = sn.name left join
     table3 t3
     on t3.name = sn.name;
```

Your question is vague on the field names.

A `left join` keeps all rows in the first table and matches rows in the subsequent tables.  It is much more commonly used than `right join`, probably because it is easier to read the logic thinking "I'll keep all of these rows".  A series of `right join`s actually keeps all rows in the last table, so you have to wait to see which rows stay.

Comment: Your formating is a bit weird.  I would have put the left join on the same line as the table I am joining with.

Comment: @Taemyr You shouldnt care for formating too much. Everyone has his own style. Me I have to put reserve keywords in CAPS.

Comment: @Taemyr . . . And I don't.  Lines start with SQL clauses, and `JOIN`s are not clauses, they are operators.  I end lines with binary operators, whether arithmetic, string, boolean, or set-based.

Answer (score 0):

I did like this, googled some further as I did not get it to work even with the answer here, joins are totaly new to me. The internalusers, external and so on is just fake to post what I did here as I cant use the real names.

```
select s.Site,s2.Total_hits as 'Internalusers',s3.Total_Hits as 'ExternalUsers', 
s4.Total_hits as 'Comapany2users'  from Database.Table as S
left outer join HITAnalyze.dbo.Internal as s2 on s2.site = s.Site
left outer join HITAnalyze.dbo.External1 as s3 on s3.site = s.Site
left outer join HITAnalyze.dbo.Company2 as s4 on s4.site = s.Site
```

Comment: this is the same as Gordon answer. remember accept the answer with the green tick if solve your problem